# MaaS initial pxe boot failure can't find data-source, where is log?

Tags: 16.04, maas

Built maas 2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.  PXE boot my first machine so it will be recognized by MaaS.

node PXE boots, but could-init fails to find data source and node hangs.

I'd love to give logs, but there is no way to get onto the booting node, and I can't find any logs of interest.  maas.log, rackd.log and regiond.log have no information pertaining to this.  I saw a 2.1 post speaking of /var/log/cloud-init.log, but /var/log/cloud-init*.* doesn't exist.

Does anyone know where there are logs that contain the target node information, or how to log into the hung node?

Does anyone know why cloud-init can't find the data-source?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the last question, after analysing the squashfs image that is handed out by the server when a node is enlisted or commissioned, I found that neither the respective `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` nor any of the entries under `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/` actually contain a single [datasource definition](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources.html), let lone one for [MAAS](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/maas.html), which is not even documented.

Looks like somebody forgot to include a MAAS datasource in the image's cloud-init config.

Comment: I think I tracked this to a launchpad bug where multiple VLANs produce this effect.  I am not sure that  I had multiple VLANs every time I had this happen to a MaaS install, but I have a VM where it doesn't happen, and I only have 1 VLAN ("untagged") on that interface.  Given my timeline I decided not to attempt to reproduce it.

Comment: Got a link to the multiple VLANs bug?

Comment: This is the one
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maas/+bug/1665680

Comment: I "solved" this problem by going with the version from `ppa:maas/next` (2.3-ish at the time of this writing). However, that exposed the real problems the MAAS has with VLANs.